# How to fill datagridview cells with database content when column combobox is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I know how to fill textboxes with its values from the SQL database when combobox selectedindexchnged is fired. I tried to do so with datagridview but the column "Position" is not showing any value from the SQL database. Below are screenshot and codes l have tried. Kindly assist.

```
private void columncomboselectedindex_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'northwindDataSet5.employeeSCL2' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.northwindDataSet5.employee);
    
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboCol.Name = "FullName";
    comboCol.DataSource = employeeBindingSource;
    comboCol.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";
    comboCol.Width = 200;
    comboCol.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn priceCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    priceCol.Name = "Position";
   
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(priceCol);
}

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Position FROM employee WHERE FullName = '" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["FullName"].Value + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader DR;
    DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (DR.Read())
    {
        string Position = (string)DR["Position"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Position"].Value = Position;
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The code always gets "Henry Walls" as the name, since you've hard coded `Rows[0]` in there. If I'm not mistaken, `DataGridView` has a `CurrentRow` property you can use instead. But you should consider using the `EmployeeID` (the `Value` of the combobox) to get the matching employee rather than the `FullName`.

Comment: [`DataGridView.CurrentRow` from MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow?view=netframework-4.8)...

Comment: @Heretic, i have tried and it didnt work

Comment: Do u see the Position variable value from db at debug mode?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, CurrentRow property works fine. Thank you